# Determine the length of string and extract the first 15 or 14 characters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, apply

Here is my data set:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Nick','Jack', 'Ann', 'Jane'],
        'group1': ['SRE_high_0101240243', 'ERS_med_140124065', 'SRE_low_110124084' , 'SRE_high_05022484', 'CER_med_11022437023']}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

I want to extract the first 15 or 14 characters from the 'group1' column, depending on the length of the string in 'Group 1'.
If the length of the string in column group 1 is 19 then extract the first 15 characters, and if it's not 19 then extract the first 14 characters.

Here's my failed attempt:

```
def clean_substr(df):
    if df['group1'].str.len() == 19:
        val = df['group1'].str.slice(0,15)
    elif df['group1'].str.len() != 19:
        val = df['group1'].str.slice(0,14)  
    else:
        val = "issue"
        return val

df['group1_clean'] = df.apply(clean_substr)
display(df)
```

I'm getting an error when I run this code and not sure whats making it fail. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are not returning anything in 2 out of 3 cases. And the third case never really happens—there is no third option after ==19 and !=19.

Comment: I'm trying to save the result in 'val' and returning the 'val'? I've taken out the 3rd case since you're right it never really happens.  

def clean_substr(df):
    if df['group1'].str.len() == 19:
        val = df['group1'].str.slice(0,15)
    else df['group1'].str.len() != 19:
        val = df['group1'].str.slice(0,14)  
        return val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.apply(clean_substr)` applies the function to every column; so in the `clean_substr` code, your `df` is actually a series, whose index is the same as `df`'s. There `df['group1']` would throw a `KeyError` exception.

You can do a conditional select:

```
df['group1_clean'] = np.where(df['group1'].str.len() == 19, 
                              df['group1'].str[:15], 
                              df['group1'].str[:14])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Nick','Jack', 'Ann', 'Jane'],
        'group1': ['SRE_high_0101240243', 'ERS_med_140124065', 'SRE_low_110124084' , 'SRE_high_05022484', 'CER_med_11022437023']}

def parse_group(x):
    return x[:15] if len(x) == 19 else x[:14]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.assign(group1_clean=df['group1'].apply(parse_group))
print(df)
```